# проблемы с выполнением функции DELETE (PHP+MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql

При вызове функции DELETE не удаляется строка в таблице, а лишь очищаются поля оставляя PRIMARY KEY не тронутым, при этом вызов DELETE из консоли MySQL работает прекрасно.

Сначала связал это с тем, что от удаляемого PRIMARY KEY есть зависимости, но такая проблема сохраняется и при удалении связей этой таблицы с другими.

С почти аналогичной таблицей DELETE работает и при вызове в коде и при исполнении из консоли.

В чём может быть проблема?

Функция в самом коде:

```
 $db = DbAgents::getConnection();

 $sql = "DELETE FROM `company` WHERE `company`.`id_company` = :id_company";

 $result = $db->prepare($sql);

 $result->bindParam(':id_company', $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
 return $result->execute();
```

В MySQL запрос исполняется аналогичный, только уже вместо :id_company, естественно, конкретное значение id

Comment: покажите как вы выполняете запрос, мы там сзади вас не сидим.

Comment: Вам надо к экстрасенсам) На ТНТ

Comment: @Manitikyl добавил код функции

Comment: `var_dump($id); var_dump($result->execute());` в студию.

Comment: @Total Pusher var_dump($id)  = string(1) "7" ; var_dump($result) = bool(true); Всё выполняется прекрасно: id у удаляемой строки совпадает, но удаление не происходит

Comment: 1. `show triggers from название-вашей-базы-данных;` в студию 2. Подмените свой `DELETE` на `UPDATE ... SET какое-нибудь поле = '1'  WHERE id_company = :id_company` - заменится на 1?

Comment: 3. `show create table company` в студию (есть подозрение про первичный ключ)

Comment: @Total Pusher проблему решил, дело было в переменной, передаваемой из контроллера

Comment: Да, хотел предложить включить `general_log` в MySQL - там бы и отловили ошибку. Но мне казалось более вероятным триггер. [Что-то типа этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7595714/how-to-write-a-trigger-to-abort-delete-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM company WHERE id_company = :id_company
```

Comment: изначально и было так, но для пущей уверенности решил добавить название таблицы